# Create user instructions for specific view

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, android-view

In my application I want to give the user some instruductions. For that I have considered to show a speech bubble to some views where I like to display the information. I thought about something like this:

[image][image]

Now I do not know what is the best way to display this bubble to a view? For the bubble I used this `9.png` but my problem is how can I set the triangle under the specific view? At the moment the triangle is static in the image. But I have to set a position for it programmaticly. Should I use two images - one for the generel bubble and one for the triangle?In the end I want to call something like this:

```
setBubble(text, view)
```

Of course I know that I have to add a lot of logic behind this but what do you think is the easiest way to create something like this? I think the bubble is an own view but how can I create it flowing over all other views in the activity?

Answer (score 1):

Log the co-ordinates of the button and display it just beneath?

```
anchorView.getLocationOnScreen(location);

        whateverView.showAtLocation(anchorView, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, 
                location[0], location[1] + anchorView.getHeight());
```

Where anchorView is the button, passed to this function onCLick of the button and location:

```
int location[] = new int[2];
```

Comment: Oka thank you the code works great. But how can I set the triangle directly under my selected view? Do I have to use an other 9.png?

Comment: aint that code setting the triangle directly below the button?

Answer (score 0):

Nun'e Chai has a good solution I think.

However if the button is positioned in a layout and not created dynamically, you could simply display this 'bubble' by using a RelativeLayout. This way you just need to position the bubble 'below' the button and to hide/show it dynamically.

If you meed more details don't hesitate to ask, but I think you can find all that you need about the RelativeLayout in numerous tutorials.